# Resultado calculo automático javascript asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Consegui efetuar a soma de dois campos usando Java Script, mas o resultado só exibido ao clicar no campo resultado, gostaria de exibir o resultado automaticamente, sem precisar clicar em nada.

***Javascript***

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () 
    {
        $('#acontratar, #ch').blur(function () 
        {
            var acontratar = $('#acontratar').val();
            var ch = $('#ch').val();

            if (acontratar == "") acontratar = 0;
            if (ch == "") ch = 0;

            var resultado = parseInt(acontratar) * parseInt(ch);
            $('#total').val(resultado);
        });
    });
```

***View***

```
<div class="ibox-content">
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nr_AContratar, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-2">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Nr_AContratar, new { @class = "form-control col-md-1", @id = "acontratar" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nr_AContratar)
        </div>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nr_CargaHorariaContratar, "Carga Horaria Semanal", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-2">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Nr_CargaHorariaContratar, new SelectList(string.Empty),
             "---", new { style = "width: 50px;",  @id = "ch" })


            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nr_CargaHorariaContratar)
        </div>

        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nr_TotalPlano, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-2">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Nr_TotalPlano, new { @class = "form-control col-md-2", @id = "total" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nr_TotalPlano)
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Faça um função separada com esse código de cálculo e coloque dentro da execução do `ready`, para que funcione no exato momento do termino do carregamento da página, segue código abaixo:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function calcular()
    {
        var acontratar = $('#acontratar').val();
        var ch = $('#ch').val();

        if (acontratar == "") acontratar = 0;
        if (ch == "") ch = 0;

        var resultado = parseInt(acontratar) * parseInt(ch);
        $('#total').val(resultado);
    }

    $(document).ready(function () 
    {
        $('#acontratar, #ch').blur(function () 
        {
            calcular();
        });
        calcular();
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Você está utilizando o evento `blur` (quando perde o foco) para chamar a sua função.

Pode utilizar o eventu `keyup` (quando soltar a tecla) para chamar a função e ter o resultado imediatamente ao digitar.

Além disso, deve criar uma função para chamar o cálculo imediatamente.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

   calcular(); // calcula imediatamente ao carregar a página
   $('#acontratar, #ch')
         .blur(function(){calcular();}) // calcula ao perder o foco
         .keyup(function(){calcular();}); // calcula ao soltar a tecla


});

function calcular(){

        var acontratar = $('#acontratar').val();
        var ch = $('#ch').val();

        if (acontratar == "") acontratar = 0;
        if (ch == "") ch = 0;

        var resultado = parseInt(acontratar) * parseInt(ch);
        $('#total').val(resultado);

}
```